# Class event handler not detecting whether or not checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, checkbox

All I'm trying to do is bind the change event of some checkboxes, by class - and then determine if the checkbox is being checked or unchecked for further processing (unrelated to my current problem).

The "nope" alert pops, no matter what - and I have no idea why.  I've read a couple related threads and the code that I've posted appears to be working for others.

HTML:

```
        <asp:CheckBox ID="cbNewMembers" runat="server" Checked="true" Text="New Members" CssClass="GreenControl CheckOption" />
        <asp:CheckBox ID="cbLostMembers" runat="server" Checked="false" Text="Lost Members" CssClass="GreenControl CheckOption" />
        <asp:CheckBox ID="cbIncludeOnline" runat="server" Checked="false" Text="Include Online Apps" CssClass="GreenControl CheckOption" />
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $(".CheckOption").on("change", function () {
        if ($(this).is(":checked"))
            alert("yep");
        else
            alert("nope");
    });
});
```

Note that I've also tried:

```
if (this.checked)
```

and

```
if ($(this).prop("checked") == "checked")
```

and a few other combinations.  But, like I said, the if statement always evaluates as false.  Please help!

**UPDATE:**

I changed the event handler to this:

```
    $(".CheckOption input[type='checkbox']").on("change", function (e) {
        if ($(this).is(":checked"))
            alert("yep");
        else
            alert("nope");
    });
```

Comment: If you could post the resulting HTML, from after the ASP.NET code is processed, it will give us a better idea of what is going on.  If I translate what you posted to HTML manually, the jQuery works just fine.

Comment: All set - asp.net wraps checkboxes in a span, so I just needed to target that class' child checkbox elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET checkboxes are not rendered as a simple checkbox in HTML.

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="oi" CssClass="test"  runat="server"/>
```

Is printed as:

```
<span class="test"><input id="MainContent_oi" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$MainContent$oi"></span>
```

So you end up attaching event handler to the `span` and not to the `input`, your handler is still fired because the change event is propagated to the `input` parents.

To get the input in your event handler add the event parameter and change `this` to `evt.target`:

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $(".CheckOption").on("change", function (evt) {
        if ($(evt.target).is(":checked"))
            alert("yep");
        else
            alert("nope");
    });
});
```

Comment: Ugh - I knew that, too.  Thanks!